# python import modules printing

Tags: python, import

I have 2 files.
**file_one.py**

```
import file_two

print("File one __name__ is set to: {}" .format(__name__))
```

**file_two.py**

```
print("File two __name__ is set to: {}" .format(__name__))
```

when i run file_one.py

its printing:

```
File two __name__ is set to: file_two

File one __name__ is set to: __main__
```

Why is python printing  the line from file_two : *"File two **name** is set to: file_two"*

I have only imported file_two, not printing anything from file_two

see example from here:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/

Answer (score -3):

You should add this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

before your print statements. See [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

Comment: OP is asking the reason for the problem and not the solution to it.

Comment: and if he reads the link then he'll know why.